# Create a nested array containing the properties of several HTML elements

Tags: javascript, json

If I have HTML such as this:

```
<ul>
    <li id="id1">Some Text</li>
    <li id="id2">Other Text</li>
    <-- more items could be here -->
</ul>
```

How can I create a an array containing JSON object with the properties of each list item in the list, something like:

```
var itemsData = [
    {
         "id" : id,
         "name" : name
     },
     {
         "id" : id,
         "name" : name
     }
]
```

Where `id` and `name` equal to `$(this).attr('id')` and `$(this).text()` where `$(this)` refers to a single `li` item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `.each`:

```
var itemsData = [];

$('li').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    itemsData.push({
      id: $this.attr('id'),
      name: $this.text()
    });
});

console.log(itemsData);
```

Comment: Yeah, I solved it the same way while waiting for the answer. Its pretty easy and i guess I'm just tired. Still ill mark your answer as correct. :)

Comment: @Husar I see, you were a bit impatient huh? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
itemsData = [];
$('ul > li').each(function(){
   itemsData.push({"id" : this.id, "name" : $(this).text()})
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/abeyet) (see output on console)

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = new Array();
$("ul li").each(function(index){
   arr[index]['id'] = $(this).attr('id');
   arr[index]['name'] = $(this).attr('name');
});
```